# Struggling with combining if functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

Goal: Working on a budget spreadsheet and attempting to use two formulas in one cell to determine the balance from expended or earned revenue.

Formulas used:

```
=IF(OR(F17="", H16-F17),E17="",0,H16+E17))
=IF(E17="",0,H16+E17, IF(F17="",0,H16-F17))
=IF(E17="",0,H16+E17),IF(F17="",0,H16-F17)
```

With every example, I'm receiving a "too many arguments in function" notice.

Comment: The error is correct. Each cell can only have a single argument, so you need to rethink your logic and rewrite the argument using nested IFs or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just your first formula, there are too many arguments:

```
=IF(OR(F17="",H16-F17),E17="",0,H16+E17))
```

The IF() statement has only three parts: the logical test, the value if true, and the value if false.

If, for example, you're trying to test whether either F17 or E17 is blank, and then perform either an addition or a subtraction based on that test, it should be written like this:

```
=IF(OR(F17="",E17=""),H16-F17,H16+E17))
```

Here the OR() function has two arguments and serves as the logical test.  If either F17 or E17 is blank, then the result is H16-F17.  If neither is blank, the result is H16+E17.

It might help if you would explain what you're trying to do in words, as I did above for the IF() statement.

EDIT: Re-reading the title of your question, it looks like you might be trying to construct a *nested* IF() statement.  In that case, either the value-if-true or the value-if-false (or both) can be another IF() statement. Here's an example:

```
=IF(LogicalTest1,IF(LogicalTest2,ValueA,ValueB),ValueC)
```

Here, if LogicalTest1 and 2 are both TRUE, the result is ValueA. If LogicalTest1 is TRUE and 2 is FALSE, the result is ValueB. If LogicalTest1 is FALSE (regardless of LogicslTest2), the result is Value3.

Something along these lines might give you what you're looking for.